# Append D3 Element in Angular Directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, d3.js

I'm very new to d3.js and want to convert this code-pen: http://codepen.io/budelman/pen/NqZwpm I found to an angular directive. One problem I'm facing is that in angular directive, I only have access to one "element". I can't figure out how to append the div#textbox legend in my angular code.

I tried:

```
// Shove the text into the div with ID #textbox            
svg.append('div')
.attr('id','textbox')
.select("#textbox")
.text(string);
})
```

But it doesn't work. Can someone please point me to the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: You're using [method chaining](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/chaining-methods), which means that when you call `.select("#textbox")` it's searching for the element with id `textbox` within the `div` that you appended, because you chained it off a method that returned the div. Either get rid of the select line entirely, or change it to `svg.select("#textbox")...`

Answer (score 0):

this is what you have in the original code,

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
            //some code

            // Shove the text into the div with ID #textbox
            d3.select("#textbox")
                .html("")
                .append("text")
                .html(string);
        })
```

which means you just need an empty div with an id and then insert html into it.
I am not sure why you are trying to append the #textbox first then insert html.
just have the  in your directive.  that way you can independently just select with d3

Comment: My goal is to create an angular directive to wrap the map and the legend(textbox). In the end, the html code would just be something like <map val=map_data></map>

Comment: that's ok.  put everything in the directive template

Answer (score 0):

I realized how silly this question was. All I needed is to append a new div to the element by doing:

```
d3.select(element[0]).append("div").attr("id","textbox");
```